# Phase Changes: Energy Loss During Expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, phase-transition

Does an object lose a little bit of energy during a phase change, such as when an ice cube melts and expands? When the object expands, it does work on the surrounding air particles, but does this imply a loss of internal energy?

Comment: what makes you think an ice cube expands when it melts? See the section "what's going on" in the following link:https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/melting-ice-rising-seas

Comment: But, in general, yes. The PV work is part of the Gibbs free energy terms. Since the volume changes in a first order phase transition, pressure effects the temperature at which it will occur.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @JonCuster What PV work is involved here?

Comment: @BobD - since there is a volume change at some ambient pressure, fine phase is preferred over another. That is, the phase transition temperature changes with ambient pressure. Looking at a PV diagram for an element tells you which of the liquid or solid is higher density based on the slope of the phase boundary. All part of the relative Gibbs free energy of the phases.

Comment: @JonCuster But I'm not sure what that has to do with the OP example of melting ice and thinking it expands and does pV work

Comment: Why do you think the volume expansion would not do PV work? A pressure cooker increases the boiling point of liquid water because the pressure is higher. Higher pressure reduces the freezing point because of the volume difference that favors water under higher pressure. It is less noticeable in everyday life because while the liquid-to-gas transition has a factor of ~1000 in volume change, the solid-to-liquid is only 10%. But that still is PV work to be done and that changes the freezing point.

Comment: @JonCuster but melting ice at constant temperature and pressure contracts not expands, does it not?

Comment: Yes, so which sign is the PV work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

An ice cube doesn't expand when it melts.  An ice cube is less dense than water. Therefore its volume will be less after it melts, not more. So there is no expansion work involved when ice melts.

See the section "what's going on" in the following link https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/melting-ice-rising-seas

Hope this helps.